# Estimate CI for number of sock pairs in drawer

Tags: probability

Here's my problem; I've described it terms of a sock drawer problem, but it actually has to do with something else (in this case surgeons doing concurrent surgeries)

There are $N$ socks in a drawer. (this is number of surgeries done by a surgeon... we don't actually have exact information as the sampling protocol is uninformative on this, but we can use a reasonable estimate)

The number of sock Pairs can range from ($0$ to $\frac{N}{2}$). (number of surgeries done concurrently)

Draw a sample of size $n$ without replacement.

If the # of Pairs in the sample $=0$, what is the 95% confidence interval for the # of Pairs in the drawer. The intent here is to define a subset of surgeons for which we can be reasonably confident that they don't do concurrent surgeries

Comment: You're missing some information in order to create a confidence interval. Usually, a measure of center (mean or median) is given along with a standard deviation. The 95% CI is the mean ± 2 standard deviations. 

You could take $k$ samples, all of the same size. Then you can find a mean and standard deviation from that data. Then the 95% CI would state there is a 95% chance that the true mean of the data falls in the range you created.

Comment: This comment is about socks only. Assume they always come in pairs, Getting $0$ pairs in $n$ trials can be used to get a $K$ such that we are pretty sure that $N\gt K$. We will not be able to get an $L$ such that we are pretty sure that $N\lt L$.